# Lock iPad orientation on a button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my `iPad` based application, a button click initialises the photo shoot.

I am taking five photos back to back. As soon as I touch up the button, **I need to lock the current orientation and the five photos should be taken in this particular orientation.**

Say, if Currently I am in landscape mode, and if I touch the button, then the five photos should be taken in this landscape mode itself.

**I am currently using the following code.**

It works, but not perfect to the core, there is a lag time. Only after few seconds after button press it gets locked.

```
// End notifying the orientation change
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

// Begin notifying the orientation change
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Can you please suggest any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

override the shouldAutorotate method(I'm testing it on iOS6 and it works):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return !self.isLocked;
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.isLocked = !self.isLocked;
}
@end
```